# How to query grant template information

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

After execute the grant statements below to make the grant template for existing grants and future grants, what command or query I can use to extract grant template info?

For the future template grants  I can use the command "show future grants in schema STG" but what about all the "grant ownership on..."

I need to query this info to verify all grant templates have been properly granted

Thanks!

"
grant ownership on all tables in schema STG to role STG_SFULL

grant ownership on all views  in            schema STG to role STG_SFULL

grant ownership on all stages in            schema STG to role STG_SFULL

grant ownership on all file formats in      schema STG to role STG_SFULL

grant ownership on all streams in           schema STG to role STG_SFULL

grant ownership on all procedures in        schema STG to role STG_SFULL

grant ownership on all functions in         schema STG to role STG_SFULL

grant ownership on all sequences in         schema STG to role STG_SFULL

grant ownership on all tasks in         schema STG to role STG_SFULL

grant ownership on future tables       in schema STG to role STG_SFULL;

grant ownership on future views        in schema STG to role STG_SFULL;

grant ownership on future stages       in schema STG to role STG_SFULL;

grant ownership on future file formats in schema STG to role STG_SFULL;

grant ownership on future streams      in schema STG to role STG_SFULL;

grant ownership on future procedures   in schema STG to role STG_SFULL;

grant ownership on future functions    in schema STG to role STG_SFULL;

grant ownership on future sequences    in schema STG to role STG_SFULL;

grant ownership on future tasks        in schema STG to role STG_SFULL;
"

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried "SHOW GRANTS ON SCHEMA ..."?